# Simple comet client in python

Tags: python, comet, tornado

I am testing the integration of tornado (as comet server), web2py and jquery, as explained [in this video](https://vimeo.com/38972256)

All components are coming nicely together, except that the jQuery comet connection is not taking place. I want to debug this, and for that I want to manually test the conection to the tornado/comet server. For that, I would like to use a comand line tool, preferably a python script. I have found [this one](https://gist.github.com/1672967). As you can see in my comment there, I am not succeeding. I have tried different schemas, without success:

```
python simplecometclient.py localhost:8888/realtime/mygroup
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: Invalid scheme 'localhost'

python simplecometclient.py http://localhost:8888/realtime/mygroup
Can "Upgrade" only to "WebSocket".

python simplecometclient.py ws://localhost:8888/realtime/mygroup
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: Invalid scheme 'ws'
```

So three questions here:

1. Is tornado doing websockets or comet?
2. Do you know of a simple comand line comet client (python preferably)?
3. What other schema would you try using the linked script?